# SBA: authenticated sba creates new session for every request

Tags: spring-boot-actuator, spring-boot-admin

I just noticed that SBA is creating a new session at the monitored application for every request as SBA is not using the cookie retrieved with the previous response but sending the authentication with every request again and again (=pre-emptive authentication).

This leads in (my case) to about 10000 open sessions at the monitored application just waiting for their timeout.

Is there a way to enable reusing the cookies instead of using pre-emptive authentication?

Comment: Having the same problem. Especially the log viewer generates a new session every 1 second. Also tried to pass the credentials via metadata when registring - same problem.

Comment: See https://github.com/codecentric/spring-boot-admin/issues/1768
PR is under progress. Hope that it is sufficient (I don't know SBA in detail) so that the team will use it.

Comment: PR is submitted https://github.com/codecentric/spring-boot-admin/pull/1793